# The expected value of a bunch of dependent events

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Suppose we have pairs of number randomly selected in $(0,1)$.

$$
(a_1, b_1) \rightarrow (a_2, b_2) \rightarrow ... 
$$

We start at $t = 1$ and continue to $t = 2$, and so on. 
At each step $t$ we randomly choose one of $a_t$ or $b_t$, and set the result to be $d_t$: 
$$
d_t = 
\begin{cases}
a_t &  \text{ with probability } p_t \\
b_t &  \text{ with probability } 1-p_t 
\end{cases}
$$
where $p_t = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} d_{i}  }{ \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} a_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} b_{i} }$

Suppose $p_1 = 0.5$.

Any ideas if I can find a closed form expression for 
$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{p_k}{p_{l}} \right]$, for some $l < k$?

Comment: - Is the expression for $p_m$ that you have provided an *estimate* of $p_m$ given data $\{d_m\}_{m=1}^n$? Or is it a *definition*? - Also, you have used $m'$ in two different ways. Unless I have misunderstood, perhaps change the last statement to "$\mathbb{E}[p_m/p_l]$, for some $l < m$", to keep sum indices separate from regular ones.

Comment: - Yes. we start with p = 1, and continue the sequential game until time $n$.  - Fix the issue with $m'$.

Comment: @Salmonstrikes simplified the problem statement a bit.

Comment: It is not a nice problem even for k=2 and l=1. I suppose that there is no nice closed form solution. May be some asymptotics.